# Primefaces widgetVar stopped working

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I've an application that was working correctly under primefaces 4.0. But when I switched to 5.0, I've a p:calendar for which I've specified a widgetVar attr before upgrading I was able to do:

```
myWidget.show()
```

but now the browser tell me that myWidget si undefined , what could be the problem here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change your javascript to use `PF('myWidget').show()` instead